# Stuck with integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \frac{\sin(a t+b)}{at+b} \right)^2 \, dt$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am stuck with the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \frac{\sin(a t+b)}{at+b} \right)^2 \, dt$$

I would like to show that $\varphi(t)=\frac{\sin(at+b)}{at+b}$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and/or $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty | \varphi |^2 \,dt < \infty$   and/or $\int_{-\infty}^\infty | \varphi | \,dt < \infty $.

So far, I know that it is $|\frac{\sin(at+b)}{at+b}| \leq |\frac{1}{at+b}|$, but as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\frac{1}{at+b}|^2 \, dt$ does not converge, I cannot be conclusive. Looking at the plot it can be stated that it converges and then $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Substitute $x=at+b$, note $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$

Comment: Nice to know that it does not belong to $L^1$. However it belongs to $L^2$. You can set $u=at+b$ and then consider splitting the integral  on $[-1,1]$ and $(-\infty, 1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. Use continuity for the first interval, for the other ones use a manipulated version of your bound ( because we have set $u=at+b$) .

Comment: If $u=at+b$ then $du = a\,dt$ so the integral is $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{\sin u} u\right)^2\, \frac{du} a \text{ if } a>0 $$ and $$ \int^{-\infty}_{+\infty} \left( \frac{\sin u} u\right)^2\, \frac{du} a \text{ if } a<0. $$ So its value does not depend on the value of $b.$ And either way, you have $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{\sin u} u\right)^2\, \frac{du}{|a|}, $$ with an absolute value. $\qquad$

Comment: Use the fact that sinc is the Fourier transform of the ideal window and use unitarity.

Answer (score 4):

Under the obvious substitution,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(at+b)}{(at+b)^2}\,dt
=\frac1{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}\,dt.$$
The integrand is bounded near zero, and $O(t^{-2})$ at infinity, so
the integral converges.

By one of those amazing coincidences,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}\,dt
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=\cdots$$
a very well-known integral.

Comment: Is this coincidence "merely" a coincidence, or is there some sensible reason, even if not an obvious one, why one should expect those to be the same?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Not that I know of, although there is a sensible reason, rooted in techniques such as my answer's or the residue theorem, for why both should be rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well, you can think of Fourier transforms ... that way reduces it to a more obvious coincidence ...

Answer (score 2):

Yet another strategy: once the original integral has been reduced to $\frac{2}{|a|}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx$, one [may invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) $\mathcal{L}(\sin^2 x)(s)=\frac{2}{s(4+s^2)}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)(s)=s$ to further reduce it to
$$ \frac{4}{|a|}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{s^2+4} = \frac{\pi}{|a|}.$$

Comment: What kind of theorem did you use?

Comment: @Botond: the linked one.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

One standard strategy is$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2iy}+e^{-2iy}-2}{-4}\int_0^\infty ze^{-zy}dzdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\frac{z}{z-2i}+\frac{z}{z+2i}-2}{-4}dz.$$I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came out with this solution:

I computed the Fourier transform of $\varphi(t)$, which is:
$$\hat{\varphi}(w) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } \frac{e^{iwb/a}}{a}\chi_{[-a,a]}(w)$$

Then I learned that it is bandlimited, and as $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\varphi$ lives in the Paley-Wiener space $PW_{a}$. Therefore, as in $L^2[-a,a]$ the Fourier transform is a unitary operator, it holds that:

$$\langle x,y \rangle = \langle \mathcal{F}x, \mathcal{F}y \rangle$$
so,
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left( \frac{sen(at+b)}{at+b} \right)^2 dt}$$

and:
$$I = \langle \varphi, \varphi \rangle_{L^2({\mathbb{R}})} = \langle \hat{\varphi}, \hat{\varphi}\rangle_{L^2[-a,a]} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{a^2} ||\chi_{[-a,a]}||^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2a}{a^2} = \frac{\pi}{a}$$